# Is there an established name for ordinal functions that don't skip cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, terminology, cardinals

Let
$$
F \colon \mathrm{Ord} \longrightarrow \mathrm{Ord}
$$
be a $\le$-increasing class function such that every uncountable cardinal lies in the image of $F$.

> **Q.** Does this property have a commonly used name?

To motivate this a little, let's say for now that $F$ is a *flat function* iff it has the property above.

*Lemma.* Let
$$
F \colon \mathrm{Ord} \longrightarrow \mathrm{Ord}
$$
be a normal (i.e. strictly increasing and continuous) function such that $F(0) \le \aleph_1$ and such that for all $i \in \mathrm{Ord}$
$$
|F(i+1)| \le |F(i)| + \aleph_1.
$$
Then $F$ is flat.

The proof is an easy exercise.

*Example.* Let $(\kappa_i \mid i \in \mathrm{Ord})$ be the increasing sequence of Silver-indiscernables for $(L;\in)$ and let
$$
F \colon \mathrm{Ord} \longrightarrow \mathrm{Ord}, i \mapsto \kappa_i.
$$
Then $F$ is a normal, flat function.

Comment: How about "Diana"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm somewhat doubtful that this is an established name for this kind of function... ;-)

Comment: My point is that it is as established as any other... ;)

Comment: Perhaps a [Louisville-surjective](http://www.gocards.com/) function? Plus, several of their [math faculty](http://www.math.louisville.edu/people/) have research interests that intersect various aspects of set theory.

Comment: @Dave: Why not "catholic ladder"? :)